# Activerecord doesnt create data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am creating this really simple app and i've never had a problem  with this but i really dont know what is wrong here. I have an account model that the only attribute is a user_id.

When i create a user everying is ok, but im not being able to create an accout.

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts
end
```

Account Model:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :credit_cards
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_accounts_on_user_id"
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

When i do

```
Account.create(user_id: User.first)
```

it just doenst create.

Comment: try : Account.create!(user_id: User.first), that will raise an exception if is anything wrong with the creation, at least you will have an error, add it to the question, and I think you will obtain an answer

Comment: Also I think you need to do something like: Account.create(user_id: User.first.id)

Comment: You could also do User.first.accounts.create

Answer (score 1):

Try `Account.create(user_id: User.first.id)`

Comment: Yep, that was it! Or i could have done Account.create(user: User.first)
I was mixing both

Comment: Or – shorter – `Account.create(user: User.first)`.